# Como popular um array de um objeto com base em seus indexes utilizando o RethinkDB

Tags: nosql

Olá, estou começando a "entender" como o RethinkDB funciona e estou vendo que ele é com certeza o banco NoSQL que mais chega próximo da lógica de um banco SQL sem perder a otimização e vantagens do NoSQL. Meu problema é o seguinte, imaginem que tenho as 2 estruturas abaixo que relacionam alunos e as materias que eles estudam:

```
// table matérias
"materias" : [
  { id: "m-1", nome: "Português" },
  { id: "m-2", nome: "Matemática" },
  { id: "m-3", nome: "História" },
  ...
]
// table alunos
"alunos" : [
  {id: "a-1", nome: "João", materias: ["m-1", "m-2"] },
  {id: "a-2", nome: "Mari", materias: ["m-1"] },
  {id: "a-3", nome: "José", materias: ["m-1", "m-2", "m-3"] },
  ...
]
```

Pelo que eu [encontrei na documentação do RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/eq_join/), eu sei que consigo fazer um join para todos os alunos em uma query quando é uma coluna para um id. Como eu devo fazer para que eu consiga retornar um array com todos os alunos e, suas matérias relacionadas? Preciso de um retorno como o exemplo abaixo:

```
"alunos": [
  {
    id: "a-1", 
    nome: "João", 
    materias: [
      { id: "m-1", nome: "Português" },
      { id: "m-2", nome: "Matemática" }
    ] 
  },
  {
    id: "a-2", 
    nome: "Mari", 
    materias: [
      { id: "m-1", nome: "Português" }
    ] 
  },
  {
    id: "a-1", 
    nome: "João", 
    materias: [
      { id: "m-1", nome: "Português" },
      { id: "m-2", nome: "Matemática" },
      { id: "m-3", nome: "História" }
    ] 
  }
]
```

Ja até encontrei um exemplo na internet de como fazer isso quando a referencia é entre uma chave única para uma "foreign key" [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219862/how-to-populate-in-rethinkdb).

> A solução que procuro eu já costumo fazer utilizando o MongoDB + Mongoose mas estou querendo testar a velocidade + a capacidade de "real-time" que ele proporciona.